# How can I restrict access until user has confirmed email link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am finally able to send Email confirmation on my MVC 5 Application

The user now receives an email and the EmailConfirmed field is updated from False to True. However, the user is still able to login without confirming the email.

My question is **how can I restrict access until user has confirmed email link**

Below is my ConfirmEmail Method.

```
    // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string Token, string Email)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = this.UserManager.FindById(Token);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.Email == Email)
            {
                user.EmailConfirmed = true;
                await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                //await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { ConfirmedEmail = user.Email });
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "Account", new { Email = user.Email });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "Account", new { Email = "" });
        }
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Confirm(string Email)
    {
        ViewBag.Email = Email; return View();
    }
```

Thank you everyone for reading.

Ceci

----- UPDATE ------

I added the code below to the /Account/Login Controller

```
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
    if(user != null){
        if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.UserName)) {
            return View("ErrorNotConfirmed");
        }
    }
```

But its returning an error. UserId not Found.

Comment: I see you have a string token, you would need to convert that to an int to get something by Id (if your database has an int value for the id), try `Int32.Parse(token);` then use that as the id value

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this code in case someone needs it.

Basically I replaced the code above with this code:

```
        var userid = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.UserName).Id;
        if (!UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed(userid))
        {
            return View("EmailNotConfirmed");
        }
```

It works beautifully now.